# OpenCV 2 crashes with stackoverflow during inRange

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

I have created a multithreaded program that gets one frame on an image acquisition thread and the transfers it to the image processing thread. The image seems to get copied entirely but opencv crashes during the inRange function call. I'm going to briefly outline the flow and paste a few code snippets to show how the images are being copied around. 
First: this is opencv 2.4.13

for the flow of data, I have one thread read from the camera and stick the image in an Mat accessible to both of the threads. I use a lock when accessing these threads to ensure the reading on CV thread doesn't happen as the same time a write is occurring on the image acquisition thread. Below are the code snippets of each piece.

```cpp
Mat Temp=Mat(Instance->Frame->rows,Instance->Frame->cols,CV_8UC4);
CLEyeCameraGetFrame(*(Instance->CameraInstance),Temp.data);
//image acquisition thread
Instance->imgMtx->lock();
*(Instance->Frame) = Temp.clone();      
Instance->imgMtx->unlock();
```

```cpp
//image copy used in the CV thread
imgMtx.lock();
frame = Frame.clone();
imgMtx.unlock();
```

```cpp
//declared variables
int LowH, HighH, LowS, HighS, LowV, HighV;
cv::Mat binary, hsv;

//image conversion in the CV code
cv::cvtColor(frame, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);

//inRange call where it crashes
inRange(hsv, cv::Scalar(LowH, LowS, LowV), cv::Scalar(HighH, HighS, HighV), binary);
```

Where it crashes, it looks like the inRange function was trying to determine the type of arguments is was getting. Below is the relevant code in OpenCV

```cpp
void cv::inRange(InputArray _src, InputArray _lowerb,
                 InputArray _upperb, OutputArray _dst)
{
    int skind = _src.kind(), lkind = _lowerb.kind(), ukind = _upperb.kind();
```

It crashes on something in that last line. I can't really tell what is breaking here but opencv just keeps calling the `type` function until it hits a stackoverflow. I have gone through and at every point made sure the images can be displayed using imshow. I realize that's not the entire picture but I don't know what else to check. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: best I can tell, it hits the infinite trying to resolve the type of the Scalar. Below is the code for that function inside opencv.

```
int _InputArray::type(int i) const
{
    int k = kind();

    if( k == MAT )
        return ((const Mat*)obj)->type();

    if( k == EXPR )
        return ((const MatExpr*)obj)->type();

    if( k == MATX || k == STD_VECTOR || k == STD_VECTOR_VECTOR )
        return CV_MAT_TYPE(flags);

    if( k == NONE )
        return -1;

    if( k == STD_VECTOR_MAT )
    {
        const vector<Mat>& vv = *(const vector<Mat>*)obj;
        CV_Assert( i < (int)vv.size() );

        return vv[i >= 0 ? i : 0].type();
    }

    if( k == OPENGL_BUFFER )
        return ((const ogl::Buffer*)obj)->type();

    CV_Assert( k == GPU_MAT );
    //if( k == GPU_MAT )
        return ((const gpu::GpuMat*)obj)->type();
}
```

Comment: I *believe* **OpenCV** potentially re-sizes, re-allocates and generally messes about with your Mats during any call to an **OpenCV** function, which means that could be happening to your `Temp` array even **outside of the mutex** in your acquisition thread, while your processing thread is copying it. I would create say 4 buffers on the acquisition thread and acquire the first frame into the first buffer and pass to the processing thread, then acquire the second frame into a different buffer altogether so you are not dinking with it while the other thread is processing it. YMMV.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks for your response. I switched to using clone which should create a deep copy with no change in behavior.That is, using clone, the crash still occurs

Comment: I meant that your acquisition code might be changing `Temp` while you are copying it.

Comment: oh...I see what you are saying. Let me update that code snippet. The Temp variable gets written to just above the code shown so they would not be changed at the same time

Comment: @MarkSetchell I updated the code snippet to better reflect how it's working

Comment: The `inRange` just uses `hsv`, which is a `Mat` with a newly allocated data buffer (happens in `cvtColor`). There's really no reason why anything odd would be happening there other that some serious memory corruption or as you say this is on windows, maybe runtime incompatibilities. Just that it goes into an infinite loop is highly suspect. What compiler are you using, and what compiler were the OpenCV binaries built with? If MSVC++, are you using debug libs in debug mode and release libs in release mode?

Comment: @DanMašek I agree that this infinite looping behavior is very suspect. I tried in both release and debug modes under MSVC. Both had the same issue.

Comment: I tried a few things that shouldn't matter and they did. I used the explicit path for the opencv include and that made everything work correctly.

Comment: Interesting. Do you happen to have multiple distinct versions of OpenCV (or at least the headers) on that machine? Having mismatched headers and binaries would definitely have potential to cause issues.

Comment: @DanMašek The headers it were found were a part of the PSEYECAM library. I'm now getting some heavy corruption in the image each frame. I'm probably missing something with the copying

Comment: Well, you initialize the `Mat` that you populate with the data from the camera as `CV_8UC4` ... that means an image with alpha transparency... kind of odd for a camera. Are you sure you have the pixel format right? | How do you initialize `Instance->Frame` before the first time you try to read a frame as you showed in the question?

Comment: @DanMašek yes, the format is RGBA. This camera is a bit weird. Instance->Frame is initialized as CLEyeCameraGetFrameDimensions(EyeCamera, Width, Height);

 Frame = Mat(Height, Width, CV_8UC4);

Comment: This is what is happening now https://imgur.com/7kUU0CT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208159/discussion-between-dan-masek-and-chris-hawley).